# Why Built-in Modules -> modal not working on HTML5

Tags: weex

on html5 Preview URI : http://dotwe.org/raw/htmlVue/8f4f21cabee879fab13daa626049f4d5?1509479282984

Also @click isn't working on web for the `<text>` component